# Error Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, login, undefined

Un saludo, estoy corriendo un login e intento mostrar en pantalla lo que pongo en mis campos, pero me lanza el siguiente error.

**Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\maquila\libreria\help\class.inputfilter.php on line 53**

Mi código del form es este:

```
<form role="form" action="<?php url("login/ingresar") ?>" method="post">
                        <input value="<?php csrf_token() ?>" name="_token" type="hidden">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuario" type="text" required autocomplete="off" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" type="password" required>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                </label>
                            </div> -->
                            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                            <button type="submit" href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Iniciar</button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

El código de mi función es esta:

```
    public function input($name) {

    $source = $_REQUEST[$name];

    if (is_array($source)) {
        foreach($source as $key => $value)
            // filter element for XSS and other 'bad' code etc.
            if (is_string($value)) $source[$key] = $this->remove($this->decode($value));
        return $source;
        // clean this string
    } else if (is_string($source)) {
        // filter source for XSS and other 'bad' code etc.
        return $this->remove($this->decode($source));
        // return parameter as given
    } else return $source;
}
```

Y el echo que busco es esto:

```
    public function ingresar(){

    if(val_csrf()){

        echo input("usuario");
        echo input("password");

    }

}
```

Me muestra bien el usuario, excepto el campo de Password. No sé qué estaré haciendo mal.

aludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Intenta con `$_POST` en lugar de `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias, funcionó perfecto.